# django tutorial - generic views 404 when voting

Tags: python, django

I got an instance of the tutorial almost working on a shared host (minor miracle). Everything works up until the voting. I'm stumped as to why it tries to send a vote to:

/polls/1/polls/1/vote/

instead of /polls/1/vote.

When I hack an url of [site]/polls/1/vote I do get the correct redisplay of the poll question with "You didn't select a choice."

Here is the whole 404 (which I hope, shows enough so that I don't need to include my urls.py, but I'd happy to if it would help):

```
Using the URLconf defined in urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^polls/ ^$
^polls/ ^(?P<pk>\d+)/$
^polls/ ^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$ [name='poll_results']
^polls/ ^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$
^admin/
The current URL, polls/1/polls/1/vote/, didn't match any of these.
```

And here is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.template import RequestContext
from polls.models import Choice, Poll

def vote(request, poll_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the poll voting form.
        return render_to_response('polls/detail.html', {
            'poll': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls.views.results', args=(p.id,)))
```

Thanks for any help anyone can offer, and if I did not post enough code, just let me know and I'd be happy to post more.

Comment: How is `action` attribute defined for your form in the template? If this happens only when you submit the form I would guess you hardcoded the `action` and forgot the first slash `/` so it POST's to relative URL.

Comment: Yes! I hardcoded the action back when it was not running in its own doc root. Thanks rebus, after adding the initial slash I no longer get the 404.
Now however I am getting a NoReverseMatch...

Comment: And just for complete reference, the NoReverseMatch was a result of using an incorrect viewname. I changed the last line of the view posted above to: ` return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('poll_results', args=(p.id,)))` and now it all works.

Comment: @TonyAdams Since you answered your own question in the comments, can you submit the answer and choose it.

Comment: @Shoan three years ago perhaps, but I have not touched any Django or Python since then. I'm not sure I even understand the question or the answer at this point.